# How to Compile C++ with embedded Python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

I have written a Hello world program in C++ with embedded python. **I am learning how to embed python code in a C++ Program.** But when I try to compile my program with the normal method it throws errors. I think there is a different way to do the compilation.

I am using Windows 10 so please don't suggest me any linux command.

Here is my code

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\Python.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], nullptr);
    if (program == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to decode argv[0]" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hellow World')");

    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to finalize" << endl;
        exit(120);
    }

    PyMem_RawFree(program);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are my errors

```
 Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g E:\cpp\main.cpp -o E:\cpp\main.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0M2Uyj.o:E:\cpp/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `__imp_Py_DecodeLocale'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\super\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0M2Uyj.o: in function `main':
E:\cpp/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `__imp_Py_SetProgramName'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:\cpp/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `__imp_Py_Initialize'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:\cpp/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `__imp_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:\cpp/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `__imp_Py_FinalizeEx'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:\cpp/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `__imp_PyMem_RawFree'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

To compile the program, I just clicked the run button in vs code and it showed those errors.

Comment: What command are you running to compile the program? It looks like you're not linking the Python libraries.

Comment: @rid I just clicked the run button in vs code and it showed those errors . And yes you are right I actually dont know how to link those python libraries and compile the program actually I am a new learner. Can you solve it for me please

Comment: I have the impression that embedding a scripting language inside a C++ program is not a easy task for a beginner. I don't know about Python, but I already embedded Lua in a number of C++ applications of ours and it was always hard at first, although I do have a long C++ experience.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same using cygwin and python at localhost.
Executed following commands:

```
$ # /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/libpython3.8.dll
$ ln /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/libpython3.8.dll /usr/lib/libpython3.8.dll
$ g++.exe  73258055.cpp -L/usr/lib -lpython3.8 -o ./a.out
$ ./a.out
C:/cygwin/home/murugesanopenssl/stackoverflow/73258055/a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ cp /usr/lib/libpython3.8.dll .
$ ./a.out
Hellow World
$ sed -i "s/Hellow World/Hello World\\\\\\\\nRegards,\\\\\\\nmurugesan openssl/;" 73258055.cpp
$ g++.exe  73258055.cpp -L/usr/lib -lpython3.8 -o ./a.out
$ ./a.out
Hello World
Regards,
murugesan openssl
```

Updated comment:

```
C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055> g++.exe main.cpp libpython3.8.dll -o ./a.out

C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055> DIR /O:D /A /X
 Volume in drive C is CDRIVE
 Volume Serial Number is 0XXX-012X

 Directory of C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055

Sat 06-Aug  02:30 PM         2,812,435              libpython3.8.dll
Sat 06-Aug  02:36 PM               708              73258055.cpp
Mon 08-Aug  04:39 PM               708              main.cpp
Mon 08-Aug  04:40 PM    <DIR>                       ..
Mon 08-Aug  04:40 PM    <DIR>                       .
Mon 08-Aug  04:40 PM            72,800              a.out
               5 File(s)      2,886,912 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  87,239,409,664 bytes free

C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055> .\a.out
Hello World
Regards,
murugesan openssl

C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055> g++.exe main.cpp libpython3.8.dll -o ./testing.murugesan.sample.exe


C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055> DIR /O:D /A /X testing.murugesan.sample.exe
 Volume in drive C is CDRIVE
 Volume Serial Number is 0XXX-012X

 Directory of C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055

Mon 08-Aug  04:41 PM            72,800              testing.murugesan.sample.exe
               1 File(s)         72,800 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  87,239,331,840 bytes free

C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055> .\testing.murugesan.sample.exe
Hello World
Regards,
murugesan openssl

C:\cygwin\murugesan.openssl\stackoverflow\73258055>
```

Comment: Can you please write down the commands for me my file name is main.cpp and I am in windows 10

Comment: Updated my comment. I am using Windows 10 for last 1.5 years.